# How do I remove a specific character from an ARM template output?

Tags: azure, arm, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to remove specific characters from an ARM template output? Specifically, I have an output which uses the `storagePrimaryEndpointsBlob` value so this would be `https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`:

```
"StoragePrimaryEndpointsBlob": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "[reference('storage-account').outputs.storagePrimaryEndpointsBlob.value]"
}
```

I would like to remove the trailing '/' from the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring function on the ARM template. 
`substring(stringToParse, startIndex, length)`

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#substring)